# List all file names from the sharepoint folder using ADF copy Activity

Tags: azure-data-factory, sharepoint-online

Im trying to list all the file names from sharepoint folder, using `web` activity in adf. but it keeps giving the empty value.

[image]

Im sure that URL is correct, as when I did not have correct  URL it was throwing an error inidcated that directory did not exist.

I have followed [this  article](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-data-factory-blog/sharepoint-online-multiple-files-folder-copy-with-http-connector/ba-p/2480426).

EDIT:
this is how my pipeline looks like
[image]

In web1  I get the token succesfully and using it in web2 as below
[image]
@{concat('Bearer ', activity('Web1').output.access_token)}

**Pipeline does not fail**

[image]

But give the empty "value" as its shown in the first image.

```
value": [],
```

Comment: Can you provide your activity configurations or activity JSON and error picture for better understanding?

Comment: @RakeshGovindula cant share json, but I have eddited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Eveything was correct in my setup, but only problem was the language. Sharepoint was set to diffetent language than English and in the URL I used "Shared documents" instead of the transaltion of this.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from web activity, you can use lookup activity as well to get the list of file names from the Sharepoint site.

After granting SharePoint Online site permission to the Service principal, use that in creating the Sharepoint linked service like below.

[image]

Then, give the list or folder name in the dataset. You can use dataset parameters if you want to mention it dynamically.

Give the dataset to lookup and run.

[image]

**Items list:**

[image]

You can use Odata queries in the query option in lookup if you want to filter the fields.